# Zero border not working in html

Tags: html, css

I am doing an example having tables in a table, but parent table should not have border. I tried, but it is working. I check in W3School css tutorial also even no result. I tried:

1. `style="border: none;"`
2. `border:0`

Both not working in Chrome

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<table id="t02" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="t01" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E4E5E0; margin-left: 40px;">
        <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
          <th>Available<br>On</th>
          <th>Ids</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Phone</b></td>
          <td><b>9999999</td>
             </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td>
          <br><br>
          <table id="t01" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E4E5E0; margin-left: 40px;">
             <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <th style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;">Available<br>On</th>
                <th style="border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px;">Ids</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><b>Phone</b></td>
          <td><b>9999999</b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: there is 3 tables inbricated and only 2 of them shows outside borders, where is your issue ? is this about the parent tds ?

Answer (score 1):

Several issues in your code...

...missing a closing  bracket...

...why using inline styles...

...IDs should be unique - use a class for your "t01"...

But main important advice: do not use tables for layouting, these days.
Rather learn flexbox, or CSS grid.